# How to tranform css hex to uppercase in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I'm just using vscode [prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode), and I was told that hex value should be uppercase as company's standard. I've been through a search and I found their [github-issue](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/5158)
that states,

> " Personally I prefer uppercase too, but I was asked to do lowercase... But changing this would cause a lot of unnecessary churn for all Prettier users... this decision has been made and is not going to change. An option won't be added." - Sep. 29,2018

So basically, **prettier** transformed hex value to lowercase, and does not provide an option to change it to uppercase.

I want to ask, have they change their decision now and made an option to transform css hex value to uppercase? And if theres no really option for this in *prettier*, is there any alternatives to achieve this?

Comment: do a regex search for `#[0-9a-fA-F]+`, select them all and then command `Transform to UpperCase`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My basic alternative that I used is the idea of [@rioV8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9938317/riov8), however I would prefer to use *replace field* instead of *Transform to UpperCase*, I think that would be more quick.

---

I would like to provide this as answer because it's at least working.

In vscode find `#(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{3}){1,2}` using regular expression, and replace it with `\U$0`.
[image]

---

**Updated: *how to auto transform after save***

Follow this link: [How to automatically run a "find and replace" after save?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72849489/how-to-automatically-run-a-find-and-replace-after-save)

Answer (score 0):

Since `\U$0` did not work well, we looked for alternatives.

1. Search by regular expression

Open a search window with <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>, click `.*`, and execute a regular expression search with `#(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{3}){1,2}`.

2. Select the target string

In the search results window, use <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> to select all and <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd> to select the target string.

3. Open the command palette

Open the command palette with the <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>.

4. Convert to upper case

Type `upper`or `lower` on the command palette and execute.