# How to automatically run a "find and replace" after save?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have some regex here that transforms CSS hex to uppercase. This was originally from my previous question [How to tranform css hex to uppercase in vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65730110/how-to-tranform-css-hex-to-uppercase-in-vscode)

```
find: #(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{3}){1,2}
replace all: \U$0
```

I want to ask how to auto-execute the above after saving a file. I finally came up to ask this since I just got tired of running these every time before I create a PR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your find/replace needs to be in the form of a command so that it can be run on save.  You can make it into a command with this extension, [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview), that I wrote.

With this in your `settings.json`:

```
  "findInCurrentFile": {
    "upcaseHexColors": {  // this will be the command name to use in the codeActions
      "title": "upcase Hex colors", // this is how it will look in the Command Palette
      "find": "#(?:[0-9A-FA-F]{3}){1,2}",
      "replace": "\\U$0",
      "isRegex": true
    },
  },

  "[css]": {                       // if you want to limit it to css files
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": [
      "source.upcaseHexColors"
    ]
  },
```

Make sure you reload the vscode window: `Developer: Reload Window` after making these settings changes.

[image: upcase hex colors on save demo]